# Custom docky icons arrows

Tags: 14.04, docky

How can be customized arrow icons from Docky?

Now they look ugly and not noticeable at all, when I receive a new skype message for example the dot is red but is not noticeable, I'd like to change them with mine, it is possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you can't, according to this site: http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=Theme_Specification

[Plank](http://wiki.go-docky.com/?title=Plank:Introduction) is a similar dock (it's the core of docky), and with that one you can edit some preferences about notifications in the dock.
To do that, navigate to /usr/share/plank/themes and make a copy of the folder that has the name of the theme that you use, and name it to something else. Go into that folder, and edit the file dock.theme. There you will see a couple of settings to edit, for example UrgentBounceHeight.